# Cross-compile base Linux for Big-Endian system

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cross-compilation

I need to test some code on a big-endian system, and it feels like severe overkill to use an entire linux distro to run one executable on a big-endian platform.

I have been working on the eudyptula challenge, so I am familiar with the idea of just running the raw linux kernel, loading bash, and quickly compiling my project (although I think quickly compiling is an oxymoron) then running it.

My issue is that I can't seem to successfully cross-compile linux 4.7 on my arch linux machine to successfully run it on a big-endian emulator (using qemu).

I installed the `arm-linux-gnueabihf-*` packages and tried `make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- defconfig` which seemed to successfully build the kernel, but when I tried 'running' it with `qemu-system-arm -machine raspi2 -kernel ./arch/arm/boot/zImage` it just showed a black screen.

Any idea how to successfully run a basic linux installation without any distribution to "quickly" test big-endian code?

Comment: You could start by picking a big-endian target ;-). `arm-linux-gnueabihf` is little-endian; try `powerpc-linux-gnu` instead...

Comment: Well, that would help... although I thought that raspi2 would be a big-endian system. Nonetheless I can't seem to find a ppc cross compilation toolchain anywhere in the AUR. Any idea where I can find a big-endian cross-compilation suite for ppc?

Comment: I don't know about AUR... If there's nothing there targeting PowerPC, you might find some other available big-endian target (check [this page](https://wiki.debian.org/ArchitectureSpecificsMemo) to quickly identify big-endian architectures). Alternatively, it's not too hard to build a cross-toolchain!

Comment: I tried using `mips-elf-gcc` from the `cross-mips-elf-gcc` package and when I run `make ARCH=mips CROSS_COMPILE=mips-elf-` I get an error in sgidefs.h saying `Use a Linux compiler or give up.` Thoughts?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, sorry!

Comment: I built myself a cross-compiled BE mips toolkit from source and successfully 'made` the kernel. However no (u/z)Image file exists in `arch/mips/boot` and when I specify `make ARCH=mips CROSS_COMPILE=/dir/to/my/gnu/utils uImage` make says `No rule to make target 'uImage'.` I also tried zImage and just Image, to no avail. (I already did make all and it didn't produce an image either). Any help?

Comment: Maybe you should try armv7a-hardfloat-linux-gnueabi- from crossdev gentoo or another source, I have compiled raspi kernel sources it has the boot console, but no another one even with many kernel command adjustments:qemu-system-arm -M raspi2 -cpu amr1176 -m 256 -kernel emu/vmlinuz -initrd emu/initrd -append "root=/dev/ram ro earlyprintk loglevel=8 nomodeset nofb vga=normal video=vesafb:off modeset=off dwc_otg.fiq_fix_enable=1 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 console=ttyAMA0,115200 kgdboc=ttyAMA0,115200" -dtb ./dtb/bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb

Comment: I have with armv7a-hardfloat-linux-gnueabi-gcc/objcopy made a barebonekernel http://wiki.osdev.org/Raspberry_Pi_Bare_Bones and it outputs nothing to the tty usual console

Comment: Or just in the qemu menu switch console to serial....

Comment: To show my attempts, I have added a new question about qemu and crosscompiled raspberry kernel with busybox in initramfs: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/56302/qemu-2-7-0-for-the-raspi2-machine-do-not-show-the-second-tty-console-only-the